# How to get relevant error message when method called with unexpected parameter?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

In Moq, I want to assert that a method `TestMethod` is called with a specific parameter.  When the test fails, I want to see a useful error message similar to:

> TestMethod called with unexpected value *X* for parameter *P* where *Y* expected.

```
public interface ITestObject
{
    void TestMethod(int parameter);
}
```

Just for sake of illustration, I could achieve this using a handcoded mock as follows:

> Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<3>. Actual:<2>. TestMethod called with unexpected value for parameter 'actual'.

```
public class MockTestMethodParameter : ITestObject
{
    private readonly int expected;
    public MockTestMethodParameter(int expected) { this.expected = expected; }
    
    public void TestMethod(int actual)
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(actual, expected, $"{nameof(TestMethod)} called with unexpected value for parameter '{nameof(actual)}'.");
    }
}

[TestMethod]
public void TestHandcodedMockFailure()
{
    var mock = new MockTestMethodParameter(expected: 2);            
    mock.TestMethod(actual: 3);
}
```

My problem is, I can't figure out how to do this in Moq.  When I set up my `Mock` and call `Verify()`, I get the following unexpected and unclear error message, instead of the message I was hoping for:

> Expected invocation on the mock at least once, but was never performed: test => test.TestMethod(It.Is(2, GenericEqualityComparer))
>
> Performed invocations:
>
> MockUnitTest1.ITestObject:1 (test):
>
> UnitTest1.ITestObject.TestMethod(3)

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMoqFailure()
{
  var expected = 2;
  var actual = 3;

  var mock = new Moq.Mock<ITestObject>(Moq.MockBehavior.Strict);
  mock.Setup(test => test.TestMethod(Moq.It.IsAny<int>())).Verifiable();
  mock.Object.TestMethod(actual);
  mock.Verify(test => test.TestMethod(Moq.It.Is(expected, EqualityComparer<int>.Default)));
}
```

Granted, the information is there, but I expected something more along the lines of, "TestMethod *was* invoked, but with incorrect parameters."  It confuses me when Moq reports that `TestMethod` was not invoked because, intuitively, I *did* invoke the mock.  I called `TestMethod` with `It.IsAny()`, as declared in the mock setup.

I've tried many different adjustments, but none yielding the desired result:

- Custom error message
- Setup with Is(3)
- Setup with Is(2)
- MockBehavior.Loose
- Different .NET platforms, Framework 4.6.1, Core 2.1, .NET 6.0

Is this simply the way Moq reports error results for `Verify()`?  I'm new to Moq, and while this behavior is unexpected to me, perhaps it is working as designed.

Comment: To be clear, this question is only focused on the failure case.  I'm not concerned about the passing case.

Comment: With `Verify` you can make assertions against the call history (has it been called? has it been more than 5 times? ...) So it is not a good place to make assertions against method arguments.

Comment: Inside the `It.Is` callback you can log the difference between the actual and the expected arguments.

Comment: @PeterCsala Are you sure?  The [documentation](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#verification) for Moq has examples for `Verify` that make a distinction between "Verify setter invocation, regardless of value" and "Verify setter called with specific value".

Comment: `Verify` uses referential equality checks against the expected and actual parameters. If they are not the same then it will count into the occurrence count. So it will not report you that you had 2 exact calls and 1 "almost" call. `Verify` will report that the expected times is matching with the actual call count.

Comment: *will not count into << sorry for the mistake

Comment: Related, same question asked for a different mock framework (JustMock):
https://stackoverflow.com/q/26175439

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be normal behavior for mock frameworks in general.  Doing the same thing with Telerik JustMock yields a similar error message:

> Occurrence expectation failed. Expected exactly 1 call. Calls so far: 0

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestJustMockFailure()
{
    var expected = 2;
    var actual = 3;

    var mock = Mock.Create<ITestObject>(Behavior.Strict);
    Mock.Arrange(() => mock.TestMethod(Arg.IsAny<int>()));
    mock.TestMethod(actual);
    Mock.Assert(() => mock.TestMethod(Arg.Is(expected)), Occurs.Once());
}
```

**In summary:**

The OP's use case (my use case) is valid, verifying a particular parameter value was passed to a mocked method.  However, the error message does not report the parameter mismatch as such.  Rather, it reports that the entire mocked method call did not occur.  This is by design, and appears to be common among popular mock frameworks.

Comment: For evidence the OP's use case is valid, see "Verify setter called with specific value" in the [Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#verification) documentation, or the same thing in the [JustMock](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/justmock/basic-usage/matchers#using-matchers-in-assert) documentation.